# How can I make an AJAX refresh like Gmail's inbox?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I'm making a messaging system and I am currently reloading the content of the div holding the messages every 10 seconds using jQuery's `.load()`, but I have a problem: When trying to make a "Select all" button, "Delete selected" button, etc. when that 10 seconds comes up it reloads the buttons and it reloads the messages, so the messages get deselected because of the reload.

What I would like to know is how to make it actually load in new messages, but not actually reload the whole div. I know that Gmail does not reload the whole div because it works properly.

This is my JavaScript function that reloads the div and changes the page title (that has inbox count) so it stays updated:

```
function title() {
setTimeout("document.title = $('#heading').text();", 500);
}
function ajaxStuff() {
setTimeout("$('#heading').load('/employee/message/inbox.php #h1_head'); $('#messages').load('/employee/message/inbox.php #messages_inner');title();ajaxStuff();", 10000);
}
ajaxStuff();
```

Here is how I have the inbox set up:

[image: Inbox screenshot]

Basically what I want to do is load in new messages with AJAX but somehow not refresh the div. I tried looking at Gmail's source but there's too much to go through and they make it confusing with a bunch of random classes and IDs.

**Note: I have searched this on Google for a while now and did not find anything.**

Comment: instead of reloading the whole div, simply append or prepend(depending on if you want it at the top or bottom) the new messages only to the div. This will require using $.ajax instead of $().load

Comment: @KevinB **Awesome idea**, but how? Are there any examples or tutorials? Thanks.

Comment: When `checking` for new messages send an ID of the newest message in your request. Then your php will return only everything newer that you add to your existing data.

Comment: @Radek Yeah, that's a good idea. So when I send it through the ajax request I wonder how I would do that. Also keep in mind that it is one table for all users (and then a `from_user` and `to_user` column in the database) and then I use the `WHERE` keyword in the MySQL Query to show the messages for only that user. So would this still work correctly like this?

Comment: Let's move our discussion under my answer. I hope it will work for you.

Comment: I wish google had both `mark as ...` buttons :-) well done.

Comment: @Radek Yeah, me too. Thanks :) Actually, matter of fact, (in my account anyway) there is a Mark as unread and read. It is in the "More" menu when you select emails.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When checking for new messages send an ID of the newest message in your request. Then your php will return only everything newer that you add to your existing data.

```
    jQuery.ajax({
        type: 'get',
        dataType: 'text',
        url: "/employee/message/inbox.php",
        data: {
            from_user : from_user, 
            to_user: to_user, 
            message_id: message_id,  
            something_else_you_need_to_send: its_value 
            t: Math.random() 
        },
        success: function(data, textStatus){
                      // whatever you need to do with the result returned from php (server)                    
        }
```

Then in your sql query you do

```
select * from table 
  where user_id=user_id_from_ajax 
    and message_id > message_id_from_ajax`
```

### update

in your php you use

```
    $from_user = $_REQUEST['from_user'];
    $to_user = $_REQUEST['to_user'];
    $message_id = $_REQUEST['message_id'];
```

Comment: Thanks... Would this be a new query or would I have to replace my current one with it? Or would this be in another page that checks for new messages? Thanks so much for your help :)

Comment: It's bit hard to tell without seeing all your code. What I understood is that you have this inbox table on a page that is created by php (index.php let's say) then ajax call refreshes the table. You can call the same php or different. Would be better to have another file let's say tools.php where you have all your code that you call from ajax. Based on parameters of your ajax you call different part of your tools.php. I usually have in my ajax parameter called `mode`. There is a condition in php based on mode what needs to be done.

Comment: What you can do now is have another button with completely new javascript + ajax call and new php code with new sql to refresh the inbox. Once everything works as desired you `only` remove old code. I think you need to modify current html to store somewhere the user_id & message id.

Comment: I already store the user ID in a session variable. So, maybe I could just add a class to the first email displayed on the page (with jQuery) and then get the ID of that element with the class (because I add an id to message [div] so I can identify them) Maybe I will just make another page (the user wouldn't see this page obviously, it would just have the query and stuff on it) specifically for checking new messages. I've got to get to bed now, so I'll continue with this tomorrow. Thanks again.

Comment: I think I've figured out what I'm going to do now. I'll just make a page called "check_new.php" and then it will have that MySQL query in it and all of the other stuff. Then I can use the ajax to get the newest messages from there. I'll let you know if it all works.

Comment: Would you know how to get the first item on the page (so I can get the ID of that and that'll be passed in the ajax) that has  specific class and apply another class to that? I know how to use `.addClass()` but is there a way to select the first item on the page that has a specific class name? Is it something to do with `:first`? Thanks. **Edit: Actually nevermind, I figured out how to do it: http://api.jquery.com/first-selector/**

Comment: I got it all to work now! Thanks so much for all your help :) You and Kevin rock! This is way better than reloading the div.

Answer (score 5):

In response to comments:

I don't think a tutorial is warranted here. Change your server code to return the "new" messages with a `class="new"` attribute, then use:

```
$.ajax({
  url: "/employee/message/inbox.php",
  success: function(result) {
    $(result).find(".new").prependTo("#heading");
  }
});
```

Of course, that code may need some modifications to fit your environment/return data.

Comment: Wow, thanks! But my PHP code just puts in all of the messages (to the user logged in) from the database, and I don't really have anything to identify "new" emails and add a class to it. I would know how to add a class but are there any techniques to see which one is new? Maybe I should add a column to the MySQL table and check if it has a "new" value or something...? I can edit my original question and add in some extra details (such as PHP code) if you need me to.

Comment: What about calling it "Opened" instead of New. When you click the link to the message and open it, it then toggles the bit to false when getting the data. Thus when you refresh the main inbox and the mail populates it would then know which have already been read/opened.

Comment: @Nathan I don't know. That's something I won't be able to figure out for you. Maybe, check the id of the latest message currently being displayed, and pass that id back to the server. Then, just return the ones that are after that ID.

Comment: @KevinB Yeah, that's a good idea. Since all the message IDs are in order, it should work right with an `if` statement, and some mysql queries.

Comment: @cgatian I already have something that says when it is read or not. I'll probably just do what Kevin said. But thanks :)